# Removing Android Status Bar in Eclipse's Graphical Layout

Tags: android

How do I remove the android emulator's Status Bar inside Eclipse's Graphical Layout? My application is set to run in full screen mode, but I'm having a hard time in layouting because the status bar is present in the graphical layout of Eclipse.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can just change the theme in the drop-down list (or perhaps better said in Android terminology: `Spinner` :)) at the top right corner in the layout editor to one of the `*.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen` options.

**Edit:** added screenshot.

[image: android themes in eclipse layout editor]

By the way, if you have a hard time creating layouts that properly scale with or without the titlebar/actionbar, you may have to rethink if you're going down the right path. If you're developing for a specific (number of) device(s), then I haven't said anything.

Comment: It removes action bar in ui editor but when I start up there is action bar.

Comment: CroiOS: Well, that's because changing the theme used for previewing in Eclipse doesn't actually change any project code. You will still have to set the right theme in your manifest, make your customized theme inherit from one or set the relevant flags in code. However, that's not what the original question (and thus this answer) was about; you're taking it out of its context.

Comment: No, I have same question. I want to my app run in fullscreen without action bar.

Comment: @CroiOS: No, please read again. The question was: *"How do I remove the android emulator's Status Bar inside **Eclipse's Graphical Layout**"*. Not: *"How do I run my app in full screen without action bar"*. For the latter you'll have to set a theme to your application/activities in your `AndroidManifest.xml`; i.e. `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTItleBar.Fullscreen"`. It all boils down to the difference between the Eclipse preview and Android runtime, for which, I'm sure, you'll know the difference.

Answer (score 3):

you can select the theme spinner and select the "Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen".

Using code:-

requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

above written code placed in oncreate method

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. In debugging process, my graphical layout was perfect on the Eclipse but not correct on my phisycal device because of the statu bar at the bottom of the graphical layout on Eclipse.
I resolved this problem modifying the Theme of the layout inside eclipe and choosing "SearchBar", as shown in the pictures below. I hope to solve this question.

[See the setting on Eclipse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OHD2l.png)