# How to remove default action bar in Android project?

Tags: android, eclipse

I have created an Android application in Eclipse and when I have setting up I have unchecked every navigation bar. I still have the default navigation bar, how I can remove it?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this in your activity:

```
 ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();   \\ or getActionBar()
```

You can then hide it like this:

```
 actionBar.hide();
```

Please note the warning about this in the "Removing the action bar" section of http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html

Comment: this is using ui: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10907782/removing-android-status-bar-in-eclipses-graphical-layout

Answer (score 3):

In an app I made, I removed the title/`ActionBar` using this code in the `onCreate` method:

```
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
 setContentView(R.layout.main); //insert your own layout here
```

Make sure that the `requestWindowFeature` method appears **before** the `setContentView` method, because otherwise your `Activity` will crash.

Answer (score 0):

First of all create a new theme/style within your styles.xml in the resources folder. Insert the following code within your resource tags:

```
    <style name="noActionBar" parent="Theme.Base"></style>
```

By using parent "Theme.Base" it creates a blank screen to work on. Then just set your android theme to your new style in the android manifest, within the 'application' tags.

```
    android:theme="@style/noActionBar"
```

Please note that if your class file for your activity contains any reference to the ActionBar it may crash when compiling.

Answer (score 0):

Go in styles.xml and change to:

`<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">`